# FIX field for maker orders

Tags: fix

I'm unsure if this question is fit for this particular Q&A board. Please direct me otherwise.

Is there a prescribed field in FIX for new order messages (`NewOrderSingle` et al) which indicates willingness to participate in a trade only as a maker (or only as a taker)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX Field `ExecInst` has a `ParticipateDontInitiate` value ('6') since at least version 4.0.

http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/5.0.SP2/tagNum_18.html

Comment: Alright, you get the cookies :)

Comment: Yay! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWac5UT80no